# Removing "-" from string variable in SPSS

Tags: string, spss, removing-whitespace

I have a string variable with personal identification numbers sorted as: 
123456-7890 , in SPSS.

How do i remove the "-" from the number?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUpDU637AiA

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE`, example below:

```
STRING NewNum (A10).
COMPUTE NewNum = REPLACE(OldNum,"-","").
```